# using stdout of a node in a launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use the output of a command in a launch file.
Think of the back quote notatie is the shell:   `hostname`
So for example something like

```
<arg name="robotname" default="`hostname`" />
```

With the idea that the value of robotname is the hostname of the machine.

How could this functionality be achieved?

Thanks in advance,
Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245224/using-stdout-of-a-node-in-a-launch-file/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2016-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would need to write this yourself.

Currently, you can only get environment variables, which would work for the hostname

```
<arg name="robotname" default="$(env HOSTNAME)/>
```

The [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) states that (for kinetic) `eval`

> allows to evaluate arbitrary complex python expressions

but I don't know what this actually means. Maybe this would allow you to work a way around this.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2016-10-07**:
Thanks! Thats it.